# How to change only one component when switching pages with nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**Background**

I want to build a web page where, whenever I change the url to another path, it does not trigger navigation, I mean, it does not load the page again; instead, I want this url change to change the properties of one component "x" in the page. Depending on the url path, it would lead the component "x" to load different properties;

**Code example**

On the example below, depending on the Link clicked, it would show a different value on the empty paragraph line: In case the url path is just '/', it should be empty, but if I click on Link 1 it should show "value1" on the paragraph, and if i click on Link 2 it should show "value2". In both cases, i dont want to trigger navigation, i only want the url to be changed and the value on the paragraph to also change accordingly.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/Link'


const example = ()=>{
    return(
    <div>
        <div>   
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <Link href='/value1'><a>Link 1</a></Link>
        <Link href='/value2'><a>Link 2</a></Link>
        </div>
        <div>
         <p> Value <p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default example
```

**Question**

How can I do this using NextJS? I know that there is the shallow routing, but according to what I have found on this issue https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3253 there is no certain way of doing this...
I know it can be done using react-router, but for the sake of learning nextJS I was wondering how could I do such a thing using this tool.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you should use page file named for query property probably - `pages/[param].tsx`. as I understand any route `value1`/`value2` will be handled by same file in that case and will be passed as `router.query.param`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Next.js Shallow Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again, that includes [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering), [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), and [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).
>
> You'll receive the updated `pathname` and the `query` via the [`router` object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) (added by [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) or [`withRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter)), without losing state.
>
> To enable shallow routing, set the `shallow` option to `true`.

---

Applied to your example:

```
// pages/[index].js

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Index() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <>
      <a onClick={() => router.push('/?value=1', undefined, { shallow: true })}>
        Value 1
      </a>

      <a onClick={() => router.push('/?value=2', undefined, { shallow: true })}>
        Value 2
      </a>

      <p> {router.query.value} <p>
    </>
  )
}
```